# How to overwrite existing .txt files after for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, export, output, write.table

I am trying to use for loop to remove the initial part of each text and then export the revised text using `write.table`, but in my folder I noticed the `write.table` will generate a set of new files instead of replacing the original ones. Can anyone show me how to overwrite existing files?

```
for(i in 1:length(file.names)){
  text.v <- scan(file.names[i], what="character", encoding = "UTF-8")
  novel.v <- paste(text.v, collapse=" " )
  word.v <- gsub(".*</Header> ","", novel.v)
  write.table(paste(word.v,collapse = " "), paste(file.names[i],".txt",sep=""), row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
}
```

Comment: How code generate new files? Isn't saving the same name?

Comment: i would read all the files as a list then do a `gsub` and lastly write them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are trying to write your files with 'two' extensions, because you read them like filenameWithExtension and than you write them filenameWithExtension.txt. If that's the case, the solution it's just change this `paste(file.names[i],".txt",sep="")` to this `file.names[i]`.

In case I'm wrong, you should show us an example of file.name's content.

Answer (score 0):

Into the code you can remove the current file `i` with

```
file.remove(paste0(file.names[i],".txt"))
```

And after that your code

```
write.table(paste(word.v,collapse = " "), paste(file.names[i],".txt",sep=""), row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

Check if the objetc `paste(word.v,collapse = " ")` will replace correctly your origonal file. I use to do this kind of loops and I have to check several times the structire of my new written file (quotes, NA's, delims, and so on)

Comment: Thanks, but your code didn't work, I am still having the original files in the folder.